# How can I test FASTSRAM from flashing our application file into external Flash chip?

Tags: arm, flash-memory

We are working on ARM processors, initially we have developed a chunk of code to test **FASTSRAM** in our project and we tested successfully in debugging mode.  After that we have flashed the same code into flash memory which need to be executed in ARM RAM from here itself.  We have done all the flashing procedure successfully. Later on while testing the **FASTSRAM** after flashing we have got *strucked* and test got failed.

Can anyone help me out from this issue?

Comment: Look at a map file; maybe post it with the relocation code.

Comment: Please rephrase the statement "which need to be executed in ARM RAM from here itself" in order to make it clearer. Your code in debug mode and in non-debug mode should be running from the same place. It exists on flash just in order to be loaded into RAM upon power up. After that, the code itself should be located in a read-only memory segment (read-only as far as bus configuration, not "physically read-only" like EPROM, flash, etc). Your fast RAM (L2 Cache or whatever) should contain only data, hence the results should be identical for debug mode and for non-debug mode.